# field [o365audit] not present as part of path [o365audit.CreationTime]

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, pipeline, elastic-stack, elk

I suddenly started to getting the error: `field [o365audit] not present as part of path [o365audit.CreationTime]`

Integration: Office 365 Logs
Version: 1.4.1
Agent Version: 7.17.3

I cannot get the logs, could you please help?

I also tried to change the ingest pipeline to see from `o365audit.CreationTime` to `o365.audit.CreationTime` BCS of the log schema

[image]

but this time gave the error `field [o365] not present as part of path [o365.audit.CreationTime]`

Comment: related to https://github.com/elastic/integrations/issues/5474

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem solved.

1. First, I've checked the related fields on the pipeline.

[image]

2. Then I wondered what is gonna happen after ignoring the failures.

[image]

3. Saved the pipeline and checked the logs.

> unable to acquire authentication token for tenant:xxx: refreshing spt
> token: : Refresh request failed. Status Code = '401'. Response body:
> {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000222: The
> provided client secret keys for app 'xxxx' are expired. Visit the
> Azure portal to create new keys for your app:
> https://aka.ms/NewClientSecret, or consider using certificate
> credentials for added security: [https://aka.ms/certCreds.\r\nTrace](https://aka.ms/certCreds.%5Cr%5CnTrace)

4. This means the secret key is expired. Created new key and edited the integration. Problem solved.